# How can i get an enum value based on other enum in Swiftui?

Tags: swiftui, enums

I tried to get a string from an enum based on other enum, how can i do it?

I want to get the icon : string of GenderIcon based on GenderString

My playground :

```
import UIKit

enum GenderString: String {
    case man = "man"
    case woman = "woman"
}

enum GenderIcon: String {
    case man = "‍♂️"
    case woman = "‍♀️"
}

var gender: GenderString = .man
var genderIcon: GenderIcon = .woman  // case is wowan at start and it's normal


print(" \(gender)")

// I tried these :
print(" \(genderIcon.rawValue(gender))")  // < - I want here the man icon based on gender
print(" \(genderIcon.rawValue(gender.rawValue))")
print(" \(genderIcon(gender))") 
print(" \(genderIcon(gender.rawValue))")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to do this. The first is to create a property on your enum that returns a value from the other. The second is to create an `init` on the enum that uses the other as the property.

Example of the first:

```
enum GenderString: String {
    case man = "man"
    case woman = "woman"

    var icon: GenderIcon {
      switch self {
        case .man: return .man
        case .woman: return .woman
      }
    }
}

enum GenderIcon: String {
    case man = "‍♂️"
    case woman = "‍♀️"
}

var gender: GenderString = .man
gender.icon.rawValue // ‍♂️
```

Example of the second.

```
enum GenderString: String {
    case man = "man"
    case woman = "woman"
}

enum GenderIcon: String {
    case man = "‍♂️"
    case woman = "‍♀️"

    init(gender: GenderString) {
      switch gender {
        case .man: self = .man
        case .woman: self = .woman
      }
    }
}

var gender: GenderString = .woman
var icon = GenderIcon(gender: gender)
icon.rawValue // ‍♀️
```

However, because you can add properties to enums, you can skip having a separate enum for the icon and simplify your example into:

```
enum Gender: String {
  // Implicitly uses the case name as the raw string value
  case man
  case woman

  var icon: String {
    switch self {
      case .man: return "‍♂️"
      case .woman: return "‍♀️"
    }
  }
}

var man: Gender = .man
man.icon // ‍♂️
```